# Smooth sidebar mouse animation

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations

sorry for the poor question title this is one that is difficult to phrase.
I was wondering how one would go about creating an animation like this:

[image: Beautiful mouse CSS animation]

Something that I did notice about this was there was another container to the right of the navbar that seemed to handle the navigation.

Any help or information would be much appreciated, thanks!

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/bradencohen/pen/NWyQOod)

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <navbar>
        <div class="nav-ico">
          <center>
            <div class="ico-bar"></div>
            <div class="ico-bar"></div>
            <div class="ico-bar"></div>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="nav-bt">
                work
            </div>
            <div class="nav-bt">
                about
            </div>
            <div class="nav-bt">
                pricing
            </div>
        </div>
    </navbar>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-ico{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 10%; /* i know its not the best way ^^ */
}
.ico-bar{
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 30%;
}
.nav-bt:hover{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might get what you want to achieve:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav.sidebar {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100vh;
  /* border: solid 1px red;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: lightgray;
}

nav > a {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  transition: 300ms ease transform;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
}

nav > a:hover {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

nav > a:hover ~ div#piece {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0% 100% 100% 0% / 0% 50% 50% 100%;
  left: 40px;
}

nav.sidebar > div#piece {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  border-radius: 0% 50% 50% 0% / 0% 50% 50% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 150ms ease width;
  transition: 150ms ease border-radius;
  transition: 150ms ease left;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```js
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const navRef = useRef(null);
  const [y, setY] = useState();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (e) => setY(e.pageY);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [navRef]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav
        ref={navRef}
        className="sidebar"
        onMouseOver={() => setShow(true)}
        onMouseOut={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#">work</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#">pricing</a>
        {show && <div id="piece" style={{ top: y - 50 }} />}
      </nav>
      <pre>y: {y}</pre>
      <pre>show: {`${show}`}</pre>
    </div>
  );
```

There is also a codepen for this [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-wave-8ekd7l)

Comment: This looks good, but it is a little different than the example. In the example, the animation seems to come TO your mouse when it is within a certain amount of pixels. Thank you though I learned a lot already dissecting your code!

Comment: You can add a nav wrapper which will be wider and apply all logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting we can open a codepen and progressively go to the solution , it's difficult to answer without some code to go on ...
what about just begin by reproduce the html and css part to begin ?

for the part that i understand :

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-ico{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 8.8%; /* i know its not the best way ^^ */
}
.ico-bar{
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 30%;
}
.nav-bt:hover{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <navbar>
        <div class="nav-ico">
            <div class="ico-bar"></div>
            <div class="ico-bar"></div>
            <div class="ico-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="nav-bt">
                work
            </div>
            <div class="nav-bt">
                about
            </div>
            <div class="nav-bt">
                pricing
            </div>
        </div>
    </navbar>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added the CodePen to the question :).